# nested calc with variable

Tags: css, sass

this is my sass code and my problem is height property for mainBox class doesn't work and doesn't compile correctly in browser

```
//design ratio
$boxHeightDesign : 628px;
$boxWidthDesign : 492px;
$heightToWidthRatioDesign : calc(#{$boxHeightDesign}/#{$boxWidthDesign});
//box
$mainBoxWidth : 200px;
$mainBoxHeight : calc(#{$mainBoxWidth}*#{$heightToWidthRatioDesign});
.mainBox{
  width: $mainBoxWidth;
  height: $mainBoxHeight;
  background-image: url("../box.png");
}
```

compiled css:

```
.mainBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: calc(200px*calc(628px/492px));
  background-image: url("../box.png");
}
```

Comment: you need space bettwen operator `calc(200px*calc(628px/492px))` should be `calc(200px * calc(628px / 492px))`

Comment: @TemaniAfif doesnt work

Comment: Make sure you read and apply [all notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). You'll also find how to use CSS variables, if you need any.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu well the issue is with unit .. there is no logic to divide px by px or multiply px with px ... so only one should have a unit

Comment: `Multiplication. At least one of the arguments must be a <number>.` and `Division. The right-hand side must be a <number>.`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the same unit (px), you are able to use SASS calculations. Use numbers by erasing units. Don't use calc, instead just `($x [+-*/] $y)`.

```
    $boxHeightDesign : 628;
    $boxWidthDesign : 492;
    $heightToWidthRatioDesign: ($boxHeightDesign/$boxWidthDesign);
    //box
    $mainBoxWidth : 200;
    $mainBoxHeight: ($mainBoxWidth*$heightToWidthRatioDesign);

    .mainBox{
      width: #{$mainBoxWidth}px;
      height: #{$mainBoxHeight}px;
      background-image: url("../box.png");
    }
```